# potentiometer rotating beyond max value when using VBUS from pico

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am trying to understand a potentiometer along with a pi/pico and I can get input:

```
from machine import ADC
import time

gp28 = ADC(28)
while True:
    print(gp28.read_u16())
    time.sleep(1)
```

I can turn the potentiometer from the 'off' position where I get values around 200 and then rotate it one full rotation to get to 65535. All of that works as intended.

My issue is that when I use the VBUS (pin 40) of the pico as the power source I get to the max value of the potentiometer (65535) earlier than when I use the 3V3(OUT) (pin 36). So with VBUS I can do one full rotation and reach the max value and then keep on rotating without changing that value. If I use 3V3 I need to turn the potentiometer to the final point for the max value.

Could someone explain why that is happening? I don't understand it at all.